# ArcGIS API for JavaScript - Search widget with external geocode service

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

To be brief, I want to add to my Search widget new geocode service that is not exposed by the ArcGIS Server REST API (more precisely - OneMap REST API - https://docs.onemap.sg/). I wonder if it is possible to add this service as widget source using Locator object and how to do that.